Cloud Run service not receiving SIGTERM on shutdown
I have deployed an express-based nodejs web service via Cloud Run. Following the advice given in the Cloud Run documentation, I have set up handlers for SIGINT and SIGTERM to enable some graceful shutdown of db connections:
    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(signal => {
        process.on(signal, async () => {
            logger.info(`Received ${signal}`);
            await shutdown(); // performs cleanup
        });
    });

I have verified that, when run locally, the shutdown process is invoked in response to Ctrl-C and kill, which generate SIGINT and SIGTERM respectively:
# kill <pid>
2024-12-19T02:14:02.371Z info: Received SIGTERM
...

However, when deployed to Cloud Run, it does not seem that the handlers are ever invoked. There are no expected log messages visible in Logs Explorer, despite having redeployed the app several times and seen it scale up and down the number of instances.
I was originally deploying from source using gcloud run deploy with the --source option:
gcloud run deploy [name] \
    --source . \
    ...

John Hanley brought to my attention the importance of the format used for the container's ENTRYPOINT when it comes to receiving signals from the operating system.
As documented in the Dockerfile reference, using the shell form syntax (e.g., ENTRYPOINT node server.js) will prevent the executable from receiving SIGTERM:

The shell form of ENTRYPOINT ... starts your ENTRYPOINT as a
subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals. This means that
the executable ...doesn't receive a SIGTERM...

So the suggested solution is to use the Exec Form of ENTRYPOINT (e.g., ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server.js"]) so that I can be sure my process is being invoked as the root process.
However, even after doing so I am not receiving signals:
Dockerfile
FROM node:22-slim
...
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "-r", "dotenv/config", "bin/src/index.js"]

Deployment
gcloud run deploy [name] \
  --image [image name] \
  ...

Before switching to a full Docker image (when deploying from source and relying on Google buildpacks), I also experimented with using a Procfile to specify the node process as my entrypoint, which is documented to be supported and anecdotally reported to allow signals to be sent to the node process when using Google buildpacks. I also tried using --command and --args parameters e.g. gcloud run deploy [name] --command "/...node" --args="..." to no avail.
Why might my SIGTERM handler not be invoked when deployed?

Are you using this style for the container ENTRYPOINT: ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server.js"]? If you using this style ENTRYPOINT node server.js, signals are not forwarded to the app by the shell. This article has more information about signal processing in Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive

@JohnHanley I am deploying from source as per the following link, and I do not have a Dockerfile in my repository, relying instead on Google to manage (and relying on it to invoke my "start" script, which is essentially "node server.js"). I think you've given me a valuable clue, thank you. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code

I recommend writing your own Dockerfile. Your method will use  Dockerfile if present. There are lots of examples to make it easy. Using a Dockerfile will allow you to verify my comment.

Hi @JohnHanley, I've been facing this issue as well, and your tip worked! Thanks! Our logs show that the graceful exit now takes place.

I've tried several things and ultimately went with a full Dockerfile that has ENTRYPOINT ["node", "-r", "dotenv/config", "bin/src/index.js"] but alas, still no SIGTERM.

Download the container from Artifact Registry. Run locally in Docker. Attach to the container and test signal handling. While inside the container, double-check that it is configured as you expect.
